# Work out full and part-time colleagues based off a declarable variable hour

Tags: python, pandas

this is more of a guidance / point me in the right direction sort of question.

**The Problemo!**

I have a problem at work that I currently work out using a *very very* long excel formula.

I basically allocate a variable of hours (let's call this h) to 500 stores

I then declare the hour's allocation for a full-time colleague and part-time (ft and pt)

The formula I have at the moment works out based on the no. of hours how many FT can work there and after the FT allocation is exhausted (basically it cannot be divided/mod into the whole number of hours) it then works onto the number of pt colleagues.

**in math terms** I allocate 20 hours to store A

store A FT colleagues work 12 hours and the PT work 6

based on this store A can accomodate 1 FT col 1 PT and have 2 hours as a remainder.

I would like to do this in python and thought it would be a good first *real-ish* project to work on.

**Solution thus far,**

What I've tried is to start fleshing out a function that takes in the ft,pt and h as arguments and spits out the number of FT and PT the number of hours can accomodate. I would then love to append this into a pandas data frame. However, I've not been able to work this out for a while now.. and I have no idea what to search for on SO

```
  def (full_time, part_time,hours):
    for hours in full_time:
        if hours < full_time or part_time:
            return full_time
        elif hours >= full_time
            return full_time
        elif hours >= full_time ....
```

Comment: yes, that's correct I allocate hours to store based off a forecast on sales and a few other things (footfall, season, promotions)

Comment: In this instance, they work a fixed number of hours. I've updated my Q :)

Comment: By the way this can be easily done in Excel too using formulas like `int(A2/B2)`, `mod(A2, B2)` etc.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, that's extremely helpful.

Comment: hey @Stuart, as divmod returns the quotient and remainder, one would need to use both formulas `=QUOTIENT` and `=MOD` to get the same result as below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I've tried is to start fleshing out a function that takes in the ft,pt and h as arguments and spits out the number of FT and PT the number of hours can accommodate.

My understanding is that you have three input variables and three outputs.  A given store with `total_hours` allocated has FT employees who can work `ft_hours` and PT employees who can each work `pt_hours`.  You want to find the number of FT workers & PT workers to allocate, and the remainder assuming that no employees will work half-shifts.

```
def alloc_hours(
    ft_hours: int,
    pt_hours: int,
    total_hours: int
) -> tuple:
    """Calculate hour-allocation for given store.

    ft_hours: The number of hours a full-time emp. works.
    pt_hours: The number of hours a part-time emp. works.
    total_hours: The total hours allocated to the store.

    Returns: tuple
        1st element: num. of full-time workers.
        2nd element: num. of part-time workers.
        3rd element: remainder hours.
    """

    ft_workers, remainder = divmod(total_hours, ft_hours)
    pt_workers, remainder = divmod(remainder, pt_hours)
    return ft_workers, pt_workers, remainder
```

Examples:

```
>>> alloc_hours(12, 6, 20)
(1, 1, 2)
>>> alloc_hours(8, 6, 20)
(2, 0, 4)
>>> alloc_hours(8, 6, 24)
(3, 0, 0)
```

In Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'ft_hours': [12, 8, 10, 8, 12, 10, 8, 8],
    'pt_hours': [6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 6],
    'total_hours': [20, 20, 24, 40, 30, 20, 10, 40]
}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Pandas supports vectorization, so each of these results is a Series.
ft_workers, remainder = divmod(data['total_hours'], data['ft_hours'])
pt_workers, remainder = divmod(remainder, data['pt_hours'])

data = data.assign(
    ft_workers=ft_workers,
    pt_workers=pt_workers,
    remainder=remainder
)
```

Result:

```
>>> data
   ft_hours  pt_hours  total_hours  ft_workers  pt_workers  remainder
0        12         6           20           1           1          2
1         8         4           20           2           1          0
2        10         6           24           2           0          4
3         8         6           40           5           0          0
4        12         6           30           2           1          0
5        10         4           20           2           0          0
6         8         4           10           1           0          2
7         8         6           40           5           0          0
```

Comment: I knew modulus was the way to go! thanks this is really great and will help me a long way with what I want to eventually create (a full labour model) you sir are a legend, consider me a pious follower of your blog! kudos for the super clean and easy to follow code not much explanation needed.

Comment: Brad, came back to this project with a better grasp of mathematics and programming and found this code to be invaluable in my project and for other problems, I've dealt with (also I know understand it, when at the time I understood like 5% of it). Thanks for this, also was a pleasure to discover that you write for realPython. thanks for the communal support.

Comment: @Datanovice, thank you, really appreciate that! Keep reading and learning and digesting as much as you can.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the assumption that you have an existing Dataframe that provides the three inputs. You could create a new column/field using the the pandas apply function. Apply takes your inputs, applies your function, then returns the results in the new field.

Comment: That's correct, or I could apply the FT & PT hours via a function and apply that against my df['hours'], my thanks to you good sir.